# What is a good book for studying incentives?

Tags: reference-request, io-psychology, motivation, economics

I am looking for a book, which gives a broad overview of all the main theories regarding incentives. Using this book, I would like to further my understanding of things like:

- Why [slot machines](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/167/can-one-understand-stack-exchanges-if-looking-at-them-as-markets/168#168) keeps people motivated to play
- Why extrinsic motivation is weaker than intrinsic motivation

Economical theories should at least contribute to the understanding of incentives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is readings on applied behavioral economics. Here is a popular favourite: [Freakonomics](http://amzn.com/0060731338)

[image]

Comment: @David You might want follow it up with Superfreakonmics (http://www.amazon.com/Super-Freakonomics-Patriotic-Prostitutes-Insurance/dp/0060889578). Not in the same league, but same theme.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to delve deeper into the topic, [If Homo Economicus Could Choose His Own Utility Function, Would He Want One with a Conscience?](http://ideas.repec.org/a/aea/aecrev/v77y1987i4p593-604.html) is a seminal paper. Then, you can take a look at some of [Bob Frank](http://www.robert-h-frank.com/)'s other publications. Among them, I would recommend [Passions Within Reason](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393960226) and [Winner Take All Society](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0140259953).

Answer (score 5):

The aspects of incentives which you are interested in are studied by psychologists as well.  I recommend Carol Dweck's work.  One of her popular books is [Mindset](http://mindsetonline.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You could check out any of Dan Ariely's books. Those are generally good at providing a similar to Freakonomics-level handling of a variety of economic topics, especially behavioral ones.